# Using onData with Espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to access a child view of a view. This is the line I am currently trying to get to work.

```
onData(withDesc("Description")).onChildView(withId(R.id.positive)).perform(click());

private static Matcher<Object> withDesc(String desc) {
    return onView(withContentDescription(desc));
}
```

But this is returning a `ViewInteraction` and not a `Object`. How do I switch this so it will work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would suggest finding a way to match the desired view items that you want to load using one of the Hamcrest matchers. Look at the matchers available here: https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree. But how exactly would I do that? I read through these tuts and I am still struggling.

Comment: From what I understand, you can only use the value of your item as matching criteria (which makes sense). For example: allOf(is(instance(String.class)), equ("some value")). Not sure about the syntax, I am trying to help from a tiny screen on a train.

Comment: When I try to use Hamcrest matcher is this context, I get major syntax errors. What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the syntax. This is the correct one: allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is("Americano")))

Comment: And don't forget to make the necessary static imports for allOf, is, instanceOf

Comment: Try import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

Comment: Well that got onData to work, but I guess I need to rephrase my question now cause I am not getting the onChildView

Comment: Feel free to take a look. Maybe you can still help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848620/onchildview-with-espresso

Comment: I'll try to as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [example usage](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/DataAdapterSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/DataAdapterSample/LongListActivityTest.java#L150) by Google's [android-testing repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing)

> ```
>  private static DataInteraction onRow(String str) {
>      return onData(hasEntry(equalTo(LongListActivity.ROW_TEXT), is(str)));
>  }
> ```